# how to revert in Git?

Tags: git, git-revert

current git log :

```
commit foo456
Merge: foo123 bar123
Author: foo

Merge branch 'master' of ......

commit foo123
Author: foo

change b

commit bar123
Author: bar

stable version
```

I am foo, if I want to revert to stable version (commit bar123), should I use `git revert HEAD~1` or `git revert HEAD~2` ? That is to say, is Merge(commit foo456) also a valid commit , 
I am a little confused.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to *throw away* the merge commit and go back to `bar123`, use:

```
git reset --hard bar123
```

At that point, you can try the merge again.

The `git revert` command creates a *new* commit that reverses the effect of a previous commit, but the presence of revert commits for future merges can be confusing and problematic.

Comment: Additionally if you have already pushed you will need to `git push -f origin branchname` so that it forces an update.

Comment: git reset directly change the remote branch, and after the new HEAD label commit will be droped , right? . And if I use `git revert HEAD~2` and then `git push`, that is the same, right?

Comment: No, `git reset` and `git revert` are very different. The `git revert` command creates a *new* commit that reverses the effect of a previous commit. The `git reset` command simply moves the current HEAD pointer back to a previous place in the history.